# multiply many matrices and many vectors pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, pytorch, linear-algebra

I am trying to multiply the following:

A batch of matrices `N x M x D` 
A batch of vectors  `N x D x 1` 
To get a result: `N x M x 1`

as if I were doing `N` dot products on `M x D` `D x 1`.

I cant seem to find the correct function in PyTorch.

`torch.bmm` as far as I can tell only works for a batch of vectors and a single matrix. If I have to use `torch.einsum` then so be it but id rather not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward and intuitive with `einsum`:

```
torch.einsum('ijk, ikl->ijl', mats, vecs)
```

But your operation is just:

```
mats @ vecs
```